# ¿Cómo programo la función donde mi tiempo limite se agreguen otros 5 minutos después de que alguien oferte algo en los últimos 5 minutos?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timestamp

Necesito crear esta función, una subasta que tiene un límite de tiempo cuando le faltan 5 minutos para acabar, entonces un postor hace una oferta y se agregan otros 5 minutos a la subasta, hasta que no haya más ofertas la subasta termina.

```
Este es el código del tiempo 

 <?php
  if(isset($_POST["tiempo_limite"])){
    //arreglo para agregar bandera cuando la fecha concluya
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua'); 
    $indicador = array();
    //obtenemos fecha del servidor
    $fecha_servidor = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    //declaramos el primer valor de fecha y tiempo
    $datetime1 = date_create($fecha_servidor);
    //declaramos el segundo valor de fecha y tiempo
    $datetime2 = date_create($_POST["tiempo_limite"]);
    //sacamos la diferencia entre las 2 fechas la limite de la bd y la del servidor
    $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
    //le damos formato al intervalo que nos regreso la diferencia
    $fecha_restantes = "<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: ".$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%s');
    $fecha_comparar = $interval->format('%R');
    if($fecha_comparar == '-'){
      echo "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
    ?>
      <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
    <?php
    }
    
    else{
      echo $fecha_restantes;
    }
  }
?>
```

y este código es cuando hacen una oferta

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('classes/puja.php');
    
    if (isset($_POST["ofertar"])){
        $puja = new Puja();
        //Si el usuario quiere ofertar por un producto

            if($_POST["oferta"]< $_POST["vmin"]){
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor de oferta es menor al valor minimo.</center>";
            }
            else{               
                $puja->setIdsubasta($_POST["idsubasta"]);
                
                $rst = $puja->PujaMayor();
                $rst = $puja->PujasegundaMayor();
                $pujamayor = $rst['mayor'];
                $pujasegundamayor = $rst['segumayor'];
                $oferta = $_POST["oferta"];
                $envioart = $_POST["envioart"];
                $incremento = $_POST['incremento'];
    
                if($oferta <= $pujasegundamayor){
                    $_SESSION['msgError1'] = "<center>EL valor debe ser mayor al de la puja actual.</center>";
                }
                else{
                    $puja->setUsername($_SESSION["username"]);       
                    $puja->setValor($oferta); //POST CAJA TEXTO oferta
                    $reg = $puja->Registrar();
                    if($reg){   
                        try{
                            $nombres = $_SESSION['apellidos']." ".$_SESSION['nombres']; 
                            $_SESSION['msgSuccess1'] = "<center>Puja Enviada.</center>";
                            
                            $asunto = "Hola ".$nombres." has realizado una puja exitosa en la subasta del artículo: ".$envioart." con un valor de: ".$oferta;
                            mail($_SESSION['correo'],"Puja Realizada", $asunto) ;
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Puja Exitosa, Correo no válido, no se notificó: '.$e->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                    unset($reg); //libera el objeto PDOStatement           
                }
                unset($puja); //DESTRUCCION DEL OBJETO
            } 
              
        header('Location:' . getenv('HTTP_REFERER'));
    }
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar, muchas gracias.
**Entonces lo que ocupo que cuando falten 5 minutos para que finalice la subasta si alguien más oferta durante ese rango de minutos se sumen otros 5 minutos mas para que se alargue la subasta otros 5 minutos. Estoy trabajando en PHP y me gustaría saber cómo**

en verdad ocupo mucho la ayuda

ya agregue esto si me aparece el mensaje cuando quedan 5 minutos pero al darle ofertar no me agregan 5 minutos mas ala subasta.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["tiempo_limite"])) {
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
  $indicador = array();
  $fecha_servidor = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
  $datetime1 = date_create($fecha_servidor);
  $datetime2 = date_create($_POST["tiempo_limite"]);
  $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
  $fecha_restantes = "<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: ".$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%s');
  $fecha_comparar = $interval->format('%R');

  if ($fecha_comparar == '-') {
    echo "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
    ?>
    <script> document.getElementById('ofertar').disabled = true; </script>
    <?php
  } else {
    // Compruebe si el tiempo restante es menor o igual a 5 minutos (300 segundos)
    $remainingSeconds = $interval->format('%I');
  
    if ($remainingSeconds <= 05){
      echo "<br>";
      echo '<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])){
      if($remainingSeconds <= 05) {
      // Agregue 5 minutos (300 segundos) a la hora de finalización de la subasta actual
      $newEndTime = date_add($datetime2, new DateInterval('PT5M'));
      $updatedEndTime = $newEndTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
      
      }
      echo $fecha_restantes;
      echo "<br>";
      echo "Se realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos 5 minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado 5 minutos.";
    } else {
      echo $fecha_restantes;
    }
  
}}
?>
```

este es el formulario donde se realiza otra oferta y mas arriba esta donde se manda ala base de datos

```
 <?php
                                          if( ($_SESSION['rol'] == 'Comprador') && ($rst['Estado']=='Subasta') ){?>
                                              <form class = "form-inline" action="app/add_puja.php" method="POST">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="idsubasta" value="<?php echo $idsubasta; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="envioart" value="<?php echo $rst['Nombre']; ?>"> 
                                                <input type="hidden" name="flimite" value="<?php echo $rst['Tiempo_Fin']; ?>">  
                                                <input type="hidden" name="vmin" value="<?php echo $rst['Valor_Minimo']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="incremento" value="<?php echo $rst['incremento']; ?>">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="existe" value="<?php echo $rst9['existe']; ?>">
                                                
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <input type="number" name="oferta" class="form-control" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)" min="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor'];?>"
                                                     value="<?php echo $rst5['segumayor'];?>" required>
                                                </div>
                                                <button type="submit" id= "ofertar" class="btn btn-warning" name="ofertar"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Ofertar</button>
                                              </form>
                                        <?php }?>
```

Comment: Podrías mirar la funciona ```DateTime```, en el manual tienes un ejemplo como añadirle x min a la fecha actual: https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.add.php

Comment: @D.Bulten ya tengo algo pero solo cuando faltan 5 minutos me aparece el mensaje que ya se va acabar la subasta pero si le doy en ofertar no me suma los 5 minutos

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría que trabajes con los segundos para el valor que vas a comparar, pues si te basas en los minutos, asumirá que cuando falten segundos no hay margen para aceptar nuevas ofertas, lo cual no es correcto desde el punto de vista lógico, si no es así cambia esa parte.

Luego, conviene que clarifiques un poco el código, dando nombres adecuados a las variables. Llamar variables del tipo `$variable1`, `$variable2`, `$variable99999` hace que en un punto no sepas de qué estás hablando. En ese mismo tenor, usa la sintaxis orientada a objetos, es más clara y evita confusiones como lo que haces aquí:

```
$fecha_servidor = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$datetime1 = date_create($fecha_servidor);
$datetime2 = date_create($_POST["tiempo_limite"]);
```

Tú puedes obtener la fecha del sistema con esto simplemente: `new \DateTime( "now");`

Clarifica también los `if`.

Finalmente, puedes reutilizar los objetos, por ejemplo, cuando haya que agregar `5` minutos, puedes modificar el mismo objeto, no hace falta crear uno nuevo.

Así debería funcionar, pongo una simulación del `$_POST` a mano para prueba:

```
# Esto es un simulacro de $_POST

$_POST=array
            (
                'tiempo_limite'=>'2023-06-27 16:23:10',
                'ofertar'=>true
            );

# -----------------------------------
# Aquí empieza la propuesta de código

$secondsLimit=300;
$limitTime=$_POST["tiempo_limite"] ?? NULL;
if ($limitTime) {
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chihuahua');
    $currentDate = new \DateTime( "now");
    $endDate = new \DateTime($limitTime);
    # Calculamos el tiempo restante en segundos
    $secondsRemaining=$currentDate->getTimestamp()-$endDate->getTimestamp();
    $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
    $outPut = sprintf("Fecha actual:\t %s%s",$currentDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    $outPut .= sprintf("Fecha fin:\t %s%s",$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
    if ($interval->format('%R') == '-' || $secondsRemaining===0) {
        $outPut .= "<b>Subasta cerrada</b>";
    } else {
        if ($secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit) {
            $outPut.=sprintf('<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar. Termina en %s segundos',$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));      
            if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {
                $minutesLimit=$secondsLimit/60;
                $endDate->add(new \DateInterval("PT{$minutesLimit}M"));
                $interval = $currentDate->diff($endDate);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNueva fecha fin: %s%s",PHP_EOL,$endDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),PHP_EOL);
                $outPut .= sprintf("%s<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: %s <br />",PHP_EOL,$interval->format('%R%d días %H:%I:%S'));
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sSe realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos {$minutesLimit} minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado {$minutesLimit} minutos.",PHP_EOL);
            } else {
                $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo hubo nueva oferta",PHP_EOL);
            }                  
        } else {
            $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se cumple la condición $secondsRemaining <= $secondsLimit",PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
} else {
    $outPut .= sprintf("%sNo se posteó un valor para tiempo_limite",PHP_EOL);
}
echo $outPut;
```

La salida en este caso sería:

```
Fecha actual:    2023-06-26 17:54:53
Fecha fin:       2023-06-26 17:55:10
<p style="color:#FF4723">La subasta está por terminar. Termina en +0 días 00:00:16 segundos
Nueva fecha fin: 2023-06-26 18:00:10
<i class='icons icon-clock'></i> Tiempo restante: +0 días 00:05:16 <br />Se realizó una nueva oferta en los últimos 5 minutos. La subasta se ha prolongado 5 minutos.
```

Observa que a propósito puse una diferencia de sólo `16` segundos. Se supone que ahí debería aceptar la nueva oferta, pues el tiempo no ha expirado del todo y además, esos `16` segundos se agregan al nuevo tiempo de finalización. Si calculas en minutos esas fracciones de segundo se perderían.

Comment: **@A. Cedano**Cuando agrego la fecha limite me sale este error **Warning: Undefined variable $secondsLimit ** y agrego esa variable como **$secondsLimit=300;** y se abre   todo lo que se imprime como la nueva fecha fin,se realizo una nueva oferta y todo eso y no oferte nada

Comment: @JAPLOR en efecto, olvidé declarar al inicio del código la variable `$secondsLimit=300;`. Por otra parte, he simulado el `$_POST` para fines de prueba porque no tengo un formulario. Debes quitar ese `$_POST` y probar el código en el contexto en que recibirías los datos de tu formulario.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** aqui en esta parte es donde envio al formulario al pulsar ofertar **isset($_POST['ofertar']**   pero no me agrega 5 minutos

Comment: @JAPLOR ¿pero, has comprobado que estás enviando datos en `$_POST['ofertar']` y que la condición de los minutos se cumple realmente con respecto a los datos que estás recibiendo en ese contexto? El código en sí mismo funciona, si lo implementas tal y como está en la respuesta.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** como compruebo que estoy enviando datos ?si el codigo asi en el simulacro si esta funcionando voy a editar la pregunta para que vea el codigo que llevo

Comment: @JAPLOR tienes que editar la pregunta, no la respuesta. Ahora haré una edición, con un código de siguimiento en todas las ramas, pues algunos `else` no están cubiertos en tu código original. Dame unos minutos para que pueda agregar esa parte.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** muchas gracias encerio

Comment: @JAPLOR revisa la nueva versión del código. Yo he agregado todos los `else` posible y he puesto, tanto en los `if` como en  los `else` una variable de control llamada `$outPut` y al final muestro el contenido de esa variable. Así podremos saber, en tu contexto, por dónde está entrando el código y por qué no está funcionando del modo esperado.

Comment: **@A. Cedano ** ok hay lo checo

Comment: **@A. Cedano** lo pongo ofertar y me sale **no hubo nueva oferta**

Comment: @JAPLOR ¿Qué muestra un `var_dump($_POST);` en ese caso?

Comment: **@A. Cedano** cambio el **isset($_POST)** por el **var_dump($_POST)** correcto?

Comment: @JAPLOR No, no cambies nada del código ya escrito, solamente pon al inicio `var_dump($_POST);` Es para ver lo que te está llegando en el POST. Es un elemento de depuración.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** esto es lo que me muestra **array(1) { ["tiempo_limite"]=> string(19) "2023-06-27 18:59:00" }**

Comment: Pues [lo que te vengo diciendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/597515/cómo-programo-la-función-donde-mi-tiempo-limite-se-agreguen-otros-5-minutos-des/597562?noredirect=1#comment1055766_597562) @JAPLOR , no estás mandando en `$_POST` nada que indique que hubo una nueva oferta. En tu código original verificas: `if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {` se supone que del lado del cliente, tienes un formulario con un `input name="ofertar"` o bien envías en los datos algo asociado a una clave `ofertar`. Eso NO está ocurriendo del lado del cliente, revisa allí. ¿Cómo indicas que hubo nueva oferta?

Comment: **@A. Cedano** ya agregue el código en editar mi pregunta y agregue el código del formulario donde se realiza la nueva oferta

Comment: @JAPLOR lo que te vengo diciendo. Observa cómo tienes el nombre del input: `name="oferta"` y luego verificas así: `if (isset($_POST['ofertar'])) {` Eso no va a coincidir nunca, debes poner lo que tengas en el `name` del elemento, o sea, así: **`if (isset($_POST['oferta'])) {`** Cámbialo y prueba de nuevo. De todos modos, el `var_dump` no mostraba tampoco que hubiera nada asociado a una clave `oferta`. Si sigue sin funcionar, debes revisar la lógica que estás siguiendo del lado del cliente.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** me sigue sin funcionar  en el principio de la pregunta subí la lógica del lado del cliente

Comment: @JAPLOR esa lógica a mi parecer está ofuscada en la pregunta y creo además que es otro problema. Como se puede ver en la respuesta, con un `$_POST` correcto, que he puesto a mano porque precisamente no tenía el contexto, el código funciona. Ahora, **por qué el `$_POST` no llega correctamente es otra cosa**. Creo que es mejor que abras una nueva pregunta con ese problema, donde sólo muestres el código del cliente y las depuraciones que has hecho.

Comment: **@A. Cedano** ok lo hare gracias muy amable

Comment: @JAPLOR Incluso, para aislar el problema, puedes dirigir los datos a un archivo `.php` limpio donde sólo pongas `var_dump($_POST);`, mientras no te muestre un valor asociado a `oferta` significa que algo va mal del lado del cliente y debes centrarte en lo que ocurre allí. Digo esto porque a veces uno mismo se ofusca entre tanto código y es mejor volver a la simplicidad para depurar más cómodamente. Una vez recibas el dato, todo deberá funcionar implementando el código de esta respuesta.

Comment: @JAPLOR en esa nueva pregunta debes poner también el código Javascript asociado, pues puede ocurrir por ejemplo que código Javascript limpie el valor del input `oferta`, en cuyo caso no se enviará nada asociado a ese valor, o quién sabe si usas Ajax o Fetch para mandar los datos al servidor. En el código Javascript se verá, si fuera el caso, a qué claves van asociados los valores, o si los mismos no se crean correctamente, etc.